# Vue3 with Vue.draggable-next drag and drop problem

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue.draggable

I'm trying to migrate from Vue2 to Vue3 of my project. It's a simple html project with Vue and having drag and drop table. It works fine in vue2 but not in vue3. Getting this error in console : "vue@next:8001 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: draggable
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement. at "

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" >
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            
        <head>       
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>           
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-draggable-next@2.1.1/dist/vue-draggable-next.global.min.js"></script>  
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sortablejs@latest/Sortable.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        
        <body>              
            <div id='myMain'>       
                    <h2>  {{ title }}  </h2>
                    {{ title2 }}                
                    <br><br>
                    
                    <table>
                        <draggable :list="schoolInfo" >
                            <template v-for='(school, index) in schoolInfo' >
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <input v-model="school['name']"> 
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input v-model="school['address']" > 
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input v-model="school['city']"> 
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input v-model="school['phone']" > 
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </template>
                        </draggable>
                    </table>        
            </div>
            
            <script>
                const schoolData = Vue.createApp({
                    
                    data() {
                        return {
                            title:"this is my school",
                            title2:'title2 here it iss',
                            
                                schoolInfo: [
                                    { id: 0,
                                        name:"school1",
                                        address:"address1",
                                        city:"city1",
                                        phone:"phone1"
                                    },
                                    { id: 1,
                                        name:"school2",
                                        address:"address2",
                                        city:"city2",
                                        phone:"phone2"
                                    },
                                    { id: 3,
                                        name:"school3",
                                        address:"address3",
                                        city:"city3",
                                        phone:"phone3"
                                    },
                                    { id: 4,
                                        name:"school4",
                                        address:"address4",
                                        city:"city4",
                                        phone:"phone4"
                                    }
                                        
                                    ],
                                }
                            }
                        })
            schoolData.component('draggable',VueDraggableNext)       
            schoolData.mount('#myMain')
            </script>
            
        </body>
        
    </html>
```

Comment: Why are the components commented out? This would explain the error as you don't register `draggable` globally.

Comment: @Thomas - I released the comment. the component code has problem. that's why i commented it out! You could run the code now.

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
 components: {
   draggable: VueDraggableNext,
 },
```

Add:

```
schoolData.component('draggable',VueDraggableNext);
```

before `schoolData.mount('#myMain')`

This should resolve the component.

Comment: saibbyweb, Thanks for your reply. I tried. now error says component is missing :(

Comment: Component is correctly registered, it is something related to the library itself. What you can do to confirm is, try & register some other Vue 3 compatible library the same way and see if it works. If it does, then you should connect with author of this library on github by opening an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the cdn version of vue-draggable-next you need to do

```js
schoolData.component('draggable', VueDraggableNext.VueDraggableNext);
```